# How to integrate $\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1}{a-b \cos(x)} dx$ with calculus tools?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

The integral $$\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1}{a-b\cdot \cos(x)}, \quad a>b>0$$
arises from the [Poisson kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel).

One can use the fact that the Poisson integral reproduces the constant function $1$ to evaluate this integral. A related approach is through expanding the denominator into a series of exponentials. But both of these delve into complex analysis.

Is there a "traditional", calculus-oriented approach to this integral?

Comment: I'm assuming you're integrating with respect to x?

Answer (score 6):

Since 
$$\cos x =\frac{1-\tan^2(x/2)}{1+\tan^2(x/2)}$$
we have (assuming $a>b>0$):
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{a-b\cos x}\,dx = 2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{a(1+t^2)-b(1-t^2)}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
If you are integrating respect to $x$ then you can use a tangent half-angle substitution.