# Is there a change of variables that allows one to calculate $\int_0^\pi \frac{1}{4-3\cos^2 x}\, \mathrm dx$ avoiding improperties?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to evaluate this integral: 
$$\int_0^\pi \frac{1}{4-3\cos^2 x}\, \mathrm dx$$

It is obvious that this is a standard Riemann integral (without improperties)

BUT

The classical $\tan x=t$ changes of variables introduces 2 improperties: ($x=(\pi/2)^-$ and $x=(\pi/2)^+$).

The other possibility is $\tan(x/2)=t$, but this change introduce an improperty in $x=\pi$.

So, my question is:

Is there any change of variables (or integral method) that allows one to calculate this integral avoiding improperties? That is, only using standard Riemann integrals.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/171066/1242

Comment: @DeepakSuwalka  You're not supposed to use \displaystyle in titles. It breaks the layout of the list of questions. See [HERE](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/18982). Also, changing $dx$ to $\mathrm dx$ is unnecessary. It's purely a stylistic choice.

Comment: okay.. @user232456

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach would be to express the integrand as $$\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{2-\sqrt{3}\cos x} +\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{3}\cos x} \right) $$ and then note that the integral over $[0,\pi]$ for both integrands are equal so that the original integral is equal to $$\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{2+\sqrt{3}\cos x} $$ Next we put a highly non-obvious substitution $$(2+\sqrt{3}\cos x) (2-\sqrt{3}\cos y) = 1$$ to reduce the integral to $$\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi}dy=\frac{\pi}{2}$$ More generally if $a>|b|$ then the substitution $$(a+b\cos x) (a-b\cos y) =a^{2}-b^{2}$$ yields the equations $$\sin x=\frac{\sqrt{a^{2}-b^{2}}\sin y} {a-b\cos y}, \, \frac{dx} {a+b\cos x} = \frac{dy} {\sqrt{a^{2}-b^{2}}}$$ so that $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{a+b\cos x} =\frac{\pi} {\sqrt{a^{2}-b^{2}}}$$ Once again the above substitution comes straight from problem no $4$, page $266$ of Hardy's *A Course of Pure Mathematics*, 10th edition.

Comment: very funny and ineresting substituion! +1

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/948764/how-to-integrate-int-0-pi-frac1a-b-cosx-dx-with-calculus-tools

Comment: @Math-fun: see last line of my answer.

Comment: Very interesting reference, Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To avoid improper integrals for the half-angle substitution

$$\int_0^\pi \frac{1}{4-3\cos^2 x}\, dx = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{4-3\cos^2 x}\, dx +\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{4-3\sin^2 x}\, dx $$

Then evaluate each one using $t = \tan(x/2)$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pi}{\dd x \over 4 - 3\cos^{2}\pars{x}} & =
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\dd x \over 4 - 3\cos^{2}\pars{x}} +
\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}{\dd x \over 4 - 3\cos^{2}\pars{x}}
\\[5mm] &=
2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\dd x \over 4 - 3\cos^{2}\pars{x}} =
2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\sec^{2}\pars{x}\,\dd x \over 4\sec^{2}\pars{x} - 3}
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{2\sec^{2}\pars{x}\,\dd x \over 4\tan^{2}\pars{x} + 1}
\\[5mm] & \stackrel{t\ \equiv\ 2\tan\pars{x}}{=}\,\,\,
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd t \over t^{2} + 1} = \bbx{\ds{\pi \over 2}}
\end{align}